# Can a JavaScript decorator add a comment to a method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, decorator

I want to use a decorator to add a comment to a method. The goal is to append `/* istanbul ignore next */` as so I can easily ignore methods from test-coverage.

For example, you can do

```
const func1 = () => {

};

// This works, and func2 is ignored from test coverage
/* istanbul ignore next */
const func2 = () => {

};


// Wondering if something like this can be done
@ignoreCoverage
const func3 = () => {

}
```

Comment: Yes, they disappear after you parse/babel/webpack them. Coverage usually runs before that, on the source code.

Comment: No, decorators can’t do that (because it doesn’t make sense). Whatever you’re using to transpile decorators can, but why use a decorator at that point?

Comment: @Ry- I find using `@ignoreCoverage` to be nicer than `/* istanbul ignore next */`

Comment: I think this is the kind of thing that a preprocessor of some kind would do.

Comment: "nice" is basically irrelevant if it gets the job done, though. They're both one liners, and they both get compiled out, having a preference rather than "using what works" feels like a false optimization here. Heck, write your own plugin that rewrites `@ignoreCoverage` to `/* istanbul ignore next */` yourself, make that the first plugin that runs: done. You get to write "what you like", and the code still gets to do what it needs to?